# how to join pandas dataframes values to correspondant rows ID and add a new rows with new data from the second dataframe when the ID not in first df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I need to join two pandas dataframes to add new column with values to correspondant rows and add a new rows with the data from the second dataframe when the ID is not in the first one.

example:

```
df1

    ID    DATA1 DATA2 SAMPLE_X

0   A     a      1        X

1   B     b      1        X

2   C     c      1        X

df2

     ID    DATA1 DATA2 SAMPLE_Y

0    A      a     1         Y

1    C      Z     1         Y

2    D      d     1         Y

joined df1+df2

      ID    DATA1 DATA2 SAMPLE_X SAMPLE_Y

0     A      a      1      X       Y

1     B      b      1      X       -

2     C      c,Z    2      X       Y

3     D      d      1      -       Y
```

So There is a new column with the new data set, empty when ID was not present. And the joined df conteins new rows for rows that appear in df2 and not in df1 (based on ID). Also, I need that whenever the DATA1 value for the same ID does not match, that they are appended, and increase the value of DATA2 by one each time this happens.
I need to add in this fashion multiple more samples. I would really thank any help.

I have tried playing around with info found [https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-merge-two-dataframes-on-multiple-columns/#:\~:text=You%20can%20pass%20two%20DataFrame,and%20df1%20assigns%20to%20merged_df%20](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-merge-two-dataframes-on-multiple-columns/#:%5C%7E:text=You%20can%20pass%20two%20DataFrame,and%20df1%20assigns%20to%20merged_df%20).
but I can't find the way to do what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The task can be split in two parts: first, you merge the two dataframes and then you update the new values. Merging is quite straightforward:

```
halfway = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).groupby(['ID', 'DATA1']).last().reset_index()
```

it is better to use `concat()` rather than `merge()`, because the columns that are not shared, as `SAMPLE_X` and `SAMPLE_Y`, would otherwise be left out.

`last()` allows to fill the NaN values and select one row only (another option could be, e.g., `fillna(method='bfill')`, but then you also need to drop the duplicate rows, if any).

`reset_index()` brings back `ID` from index to regular column, as we are going to use it in the next step, which is as follows.

```
to_update = halfway.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: len(x)>1)
agg_vals = to_update.agg({'DATA1': lambda x: ",".join(x.to_list()), 'DATA2': sum})
    
halfway.loc[to_update.index[0], 'DATA1'] = agg_vals['DATA1']
halfway.loc[to_update.index[0], 'DATA2'] = agg_vals['DATA2']
```

First, we select those rows which needs to be updated (groupby + filter). Then we compute the new values and get rid of NaNs.

The problem was that `aggr()` allows to get the new values of `DATA1` and `DATA2`, but doesn't allow to return the values of the other columns unchanged. So I assigned the new values one by one (although I don't think that's a great solution).

Finally, we propagate the values of X and Y as before:

```
halfway.groupby('ID').first().reset_index()
```

This solution assumes that the only value of `SAMPLE_X` is X, and, as well, that `SAMPLE_Y` only has value Y, as showed by your example.